# svn: E160028: Commit failed

Tags: svn, commit

I have an error with my SVN:

> Some of selected resources were not committed.
>
> svn: E160013: Commit failed (details follow):
> svn: E160013: File not found: transaction '703-k3', path '/MainApp/trunk/Praxis/plugins/id.co.smltech.framework.praxis.analytica.plugin.modulemanagement/src/id/co/smltech/framework/praxis/analytica/plugin/modulemanagement/controller/action/ActionPrivilege.java'

What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score -3):

Do `svn update folder` and then use `svn commit`.